Git command to verify all submodules exist recursively
There's an annoying bug in Gitlab CI which means it occasionally only fetches direct submodules or a repo, not submodules of submodules (i.e. it isn't recursive).
Is there a git command I can use to verify that all of the submodules of submodules exist and have the right commit checked out? No hacky output parsing please!

git submodule foreach --recursive pwd

would probably be the simplest. See git help submodule.
Also try git submodule status --recursive.

Doesn't work. If you don't initialise the submodules it just ignores them.

@Timmmm May be git submodule update --init --recursive to update instead of just verifying? git submodule update --init --no-fetch --recursive?
